# Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, enums, selectmanycheckbox

I want to use enum values in a `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`. The checkboxes get populated correctly, however, when selecting some values and submitting them, their runtime type is `String`, and not enum. My code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{userController.roles}" layout="pageDirection">
     <f:selectItems value="#{userController.rolesSelectMany}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

UserController class (SecurityRole is an enum type):

```
public SelectItem[] getRolesSelectMany() {
    SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[SecurityRole.values().length];

    int i = 0;
    for (SecurityRole role : SecurityRole.values()) {
        items[i++] = new SelectItem(role, role.toString());
    }
    return items;
}     

public List<SecurityRole> getRoles() {
     getCurrent().getRoles();
}

public void setRoles(List<SecurityRole> roles) {
     getCurrent().setRoles(roles);
}
```

When JSF calls the setRoles method, it contains a list of type String, and not the enum type. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This problem is not specifically related to enums. You would have the same problem with other `List` types for which JSF has builtin converters, e.g. `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, etcetera.

The problem is that EL operates runtime and that generic type information is lost during runtime. So in essence, JSF/EL doesn't know anything about the parameterized type of the `List` and defaults to `String` unless otherwise specified by an explicit `Converter`. In theory, it would have been possible using nasty reflection hacks with help of [`ParameterizedType#getActualTypeArguments()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29), but the JSF/EL developers may have their reasons for not doing this.

You really need to explicitly define a converter for this. Since JSF already ships with a builtin [`EnumConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/EnumConverter.html) (which isn't useable standalone in this particular case because you have to specify the enum type during runtime), you could just extend it as follows:

```
package com.example;

import javax.faces.convert.EnumConverter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(value="securityRoleConverter")
public class SecurityRoleConverter extends EnumConverter {

    public SecurityRoleConverter() {
        super(SecurityRole.class);
    }

}
```

And use it as follows:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{userController.roles}" converter="securityRoleConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{userController.rolesSelectMany}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

or

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{userController.roles}">
    <f:converter converterId="securityRoleConverter" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{userController.rolesSelectMany}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

---

A bit more generic (and hacky) solution would be to storing the enum type as component attribute.

```
package com.example;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(value="genericEnumConverter")
public class GenericEnumConverter implements Converter {

    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE = "GenericEnumConverter.enumType";

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Enum) {
            component.getAttributes().put(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE, value.getClass());
            return ((Enum<?>) value).name();
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Value is not an enum: " + value.getClass()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Class<Enum> enumType = (Class<Enum>) component.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE);
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(enumType, value);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Value is not an enum of type: " + enumType));
        }
    }

}
```

It's useable on all kinds of `List<Enum>` using converter ID `genericEnumConverter`. For `List<Double>`, `List<Integer>`, etc one would have used the builtin converters `javax.faces.Double`, `javax.faces.Integer` and so on. The builtin Enum converter is by the way unsuitable due to the inability to specify the target enum type (a `Class<Enum>`) from the view side on. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers exactly this converter [out the box](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter).

Note that for a normal `Enum` property, the builtin `EnumConverter` already suffices. JSF will instantiate it automagically with the right target enum type.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a nasty reflection hack. frameworks do that, more type info, more happiness. JSF guys are probably overwhelmed by the complexity of their creation, they don't have time for this.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you for yet another informative and helpful answer. If I may be so bold, may I ask why you chose to extend `EnumConverter` instead of delegating to an instance of it?

Comment: @Nick: in order to set the desired enum class via `super`.

Comment: With OmniFaces 3.0 the `GenericEnumConverter` has gone, as this has been solved in JSF 2.3. See https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/286 for details.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the **List** could just as well be an array **SomeType[]**, and in this case no explicit converter is needed.

Generic erasure was a clever way of putting generics into the language without breaking the old stuff, but now we live forever with the consequences of that decision...