# Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter' - Why do I need a Converter in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters, selectonemenu

I have problems understanding how to use selection in JSF 2 with POJO/entity effectively. For example, I'm trying to select a `Warehouse` entity via the below dropdown:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedWarehouse}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose one .." itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableWarehouses}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And the below managed bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private Warehouse selectedWarehouse;
    private List<SelectItem> availableWarehouses;

    // ...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...

        availableWarehouses = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Warehouse warehouse : warehouseService.listAll()) {
            availableWarehouses.add(new SelectItem(warehouse, warehouse.getName()));
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice that I use the whole `Warehouse` entity as the value of `SelectItem`.

When I submit the form, this fails with the following faces message:

> Conversion Error setting value 'com.example.Warehouse@cafebabe' for 'null Converter'.

I was hoping that JSF could just set the correct `Warehouse` object to my managed bean when I wrap it in a `SelectItem`. Wrapping my entity inside the `SelectItem` was meant to skip creating a `Converter` for my entity.

Do I really have to use a `Converter` whenever I want to make use of entities in my `<h:selectOneMenu>`? It should for JSF be possible to just extract the selected item from the list of available items. If I really have to use a converter, what is the practical way of doing it? So far I came up to this:

1. Create a `Converter` implementation for the entity.
2. Overriding the `getAsString()`. I think I don't need this since the label property of the `SelectItem` will be used to display the dropdown option label.
3. Overriding the `getAsObject()`. I think this will be used to return the correct `SelectItem` or entity depending on the type of the selected field defined in the managed bean.

The `getAsObject()` confuses me. What is the efficient way to do this? Having the string value, how do I get the associated entity object? Should I query the entity object from the service object based on the string value and return the entity? Or perhaps somehow I can access the list of the entities that form the selection items, loop them to find the correct entity, and return the entity?

What is the normal approach of this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

## Introduction

JSF generates HTML. HTML is in Java terms basically one large `String`. To represent Java objects in HTML, they have to be converted to `String`. Also, when a HTML form is submitted, the submitted values are treated as `String` in the HTTP request parameters. Under the covers, JSF extracts them from the [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#getParameter-java.lang.String-) which returns `String`.

To convert between a non-standard Java object (i.e. not a `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` for which EL has builtin conversions, or `Date`/`LocalDate`/`ZonedDateTime` for which JSF provides builtin [`<f:convertDateTime>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/2.3/vdldoc/f/convertdatetime) tag), you really have to supply a custom [`Converter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/jakarta/faces/convert/converter). The `SelectItem` has no special purpose at all. It's just a leftover from JSF 1.x when it wasn't possible to supply e.g. `List<Warehouse>` directly to `<f:selectItems>`. It has also no special treatment as to labels and conversion.

## getAsString()

You need to implement [`getAsString()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/jakarta/faces/convert/converter#getAsString(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext,jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent,T)) method in such way that the desired Java object is been represented in an **unique** `String`  representation which can be used as HTTP request parameter. Normally, the technical ID (the database primary key) is used here.

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
    if (modelValue == null) {
        return ""; // Never return null here!
    }

    if (modelValue instanceof Warehouse) {
        return String.valueOf(((Warehouse) modelValue).getId());
    } else {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(modelValue + " is not a valid Warehouse"));
    }
}
```

Note that returning an empty string in case of a null/empty model value is significant and required by the [javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/jakarta/faces/convert/converter#getAsString(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext,jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent,T)):

> Returns: a zero-length String if value is null, otherwise the result of the conversion

Otherwise the generated `<option>` will not have a `value` attribute and by default send the item label back into `getAsObject()`. See also [Using a "Please select" f:selectItem with null/empty value inside a p:selectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052503/using-a-please-select-fselectitem-with-null-empty-value-inside-a-pselectonem/24321980#24321980).

## getAsObject()

You need to implement [`getAsObject()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/jakarta/faces/convert/converter#getAsObject(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext,jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent,java.lang.String)) in such way that **exactly** that `String` representation as returned by `getAsString()` can be converted back to **exactly** the same Java object specified as `modelValue` in `getAsString()`.

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
    if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return warehouseService.find(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(submittedValue + " is not a valid Warehouse ID"), e);
    }
}
```

In other words, you must be technically able to pass back the returned object as `modelValue` argument of `getAsString()` and then pass back the obtained string as `submittedValue` argument of `getAsObject()` in an infinite loop.

## Usage

Finally just annotate the `Converter` with [`@FacesConverter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/convert/facesconverter) to hook on the object type in question, JSF will then automatically take care of conversion when `Warehouse` type ever comes into the picture:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Warehouse.class)
```

That was the "canonical" JSF approach. It's after all not very effective as it could indeed also just have grabbed the item from the `<f:selectItems>`. But the most important point of a `Converter` is that it returns an **unique** `String` representation, so that the Java object could be identified by a simple `String` suitable for passing around in HTTP and HTML.

## Generic converter based on toString()

JSF utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org) has a [`SelectItemsConverter`](https://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/converter/SelectItemsConverter.html) which works based on `toString()` outcome of the entity. This way you do not need to fiddle with `getAsObject()` and expensive business/database operations anymore. For some concrete use examples, see also the [showcase](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter).

To use it, just register it as below:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
```

And make sure that the `toString()` of your `Warehouse` entity returns an **unique** representation of the entity. You could for instance directly return the ID:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
}
```

Or something more readable/reusable:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Warehouse[id=" + id + "]";
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-with-complex-objects-entities-from-a-db)
- [Generic JSF entity converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343032/implement-converters-for-entities-with-java-generics) - so that you don't need to write a converter for *every* entity.
- [Using enums in JSF selectitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/jsf-2-0-use-enum-in-selectmany-menu) - enums needs to be treated a bit differently
- [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/how-to-inject-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autowired-etc-in-facesconve)

---

**Unrelated** to the problem, since JSF 2.0 it's not explicitly required anymore to have a `List<SelectItem>` as `<f:selectItem>` value. Just a `List<Warehouse>` would also suffice.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedWarehouse}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose one .." itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableWarehouses}" var="warehouse"
        itemLabel="#{warehouse.name}" itemValue="#{warehouse}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

```
private Warehouse selectedWarehouse;
private List<Warehouse> availableWarehouses;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer, it solved my problem ! The generic JSF entity converter is very nice !

Comment: Hello @BalusC, I have implemented this solution and it works, but I see just one problem. If I try to move the custom converter file to a separated bean, then when I reload the page it says "Expression Error: Object with name MyCustomCoverter not found.". So this text `<f:converter converterId="MyCustomConverter"/>` cannot locate the converter. Now, how can I make it work?

Comment: I was missing the `<f:converter converterId="ContactConverter" />` part. Thank you @BalusC for pointing me the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

**Example of JSF generic converter with ABaseEntity and identifier:**

*ABaseEntity.java*

```
public abstract class ABaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public abstract Long getIdentifier();
}
```

*SelectItemToEntityConverter.java*

```
@FacesConverter(value = "SelectItemToEntityConverter")
public class SelectItemToEntityConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, String value) {
        Object o = null;
        if (!(value == null || value.isEmpty())) {
            o = this.getSelectedItemAsEntity(comp, value);
        }
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, Object value) {
        String s = "";
        if (value != null) {
            s = ((ABaseEntity) value).getIdentifier().toString();
        }
        return s;
    }

    private ABaseEntity getSelectedItemAsEntity(UIComponent comp, String value) {
        ABaseEntity item = null;

        List<ABaseEntity> selectItems = null;
        for (UIComponent uic : comp.getChildren()) {
            if (uic instanceof UISelectItems) {
                Long itemId = Long.valueOf(value);
                selectItems = (List<ABaseEntity>) ((UISelectItems) uic).getValue();

                if (itemId != null && selectItems != null && !selectItems.isEmpty()) {
                    Predicate<ABaseEntity> predicate = i -> i.getIdentifier().equals(itemId);
                    item = selectItems.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst().orElse(null);
                }
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

**And usage:**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="somItems" value="#{exampleBean.selectedItem}" converter="SelectItemToEntityConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="< select item >" itemValue="#{null}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{exampleBean.availableItems}" var="item" itemLabel="${item.identifier}" itemValue="#{item}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: This is already in another Q/A referenced in the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343032/implement-converters-for-entities-with-java-generics

Comment: Difference is that there is no need for service and database calls.

Comment: please explain in more detail IN ypur answer

Comment: Don't forget that the availableItems should be a list in this case. We used a HashMap and changed it to List.

Comment: This will not work with, for example, a `p:autoComplete`

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by simply changing the type for "value" in <h:selectOneMenu.. to a String.

Comment: That's not really a solution. You would need to convert that string to an object at some point.

Comment: Yes thats right I realised later that it was a stop gap