# p:autoComplete itemLabel throws "The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'label'."

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, label, converters

I'm changing from IceFaces to PrimeFaces (I really wanted to change to RichFaces but cause a bug in new version, I won't) and I'm havinng some dificults to implement correctly primefaces autoComplete. According to his manual I just need to implement a method that returns a list of objects, and in this case a converter is required.

The list I'm returning is a list of javax.faces.model.SelectItem, I really can't understand why I need to create a converter to this, but lets continue. I've created a simple converter just to test, but primefaces don't recognizes my converter and returns this error in browser:

> /resources/components/popups/popupBuscaPessoa.xhtml @35,41 itemLabel="#{pessoa.label}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'label'.

This is my conversor class (just to test):

```
public class ConversorSelectItem implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {      
     if (value!=null && value.isEmpty())
         return null;

     SelectItem selectItem=new SelectItem();
     selectItem.setLabel(value);
     return selectItem;     
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
    return ((SelectItem)object).getLabel();
}
}
```

This is where I try use p:autocomplete:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{modeloPopupBuscaPessoa.itemSelecionado}"
            completeMethod="#{controladorSugestaoPessoa.atualizarSugestoes}"
            var="pessoa" itemLabel="#{pessoa.label}" itemValue="#{pessoa.value}"
            converter="#{conversorSelectItem}"/>
```

Did I do something wrong? Isn't there a default converter for SelectItem? Is there a easier way to implement this converter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't feed it with `List<SelectItem>`. You should feed it with `List<Pessoa>`. You should also not concentrate on converting `SelectItem`. You should concentrate on converting the item value, which is `Pessoa`. The `SelectItem` is a leftover from the old JSF 1.x ages. In JSF 2.x this is not mandatory anymore, thanks to the `var`, `itemValue` and `itemLabel` attributes in the view. This keeps your bean clean from view-specific clutter.

The `Converter` is only necessary whenever you use `itemValue="#{pessoa}"` and the `#{modeloPopupBuscaPessoa.itemSelecionado}` refers a `Pessoa` property. You should then in `getAsString()` convert `Pessoa` to its unique `String` representation (so that it can be printed in HTML) and in `getAsObject()` convert from `String` to `Pessoa` (so that it can be set in bean property).

However, if `#{pessoa.value}` is a `String` and `#{modeloPopupBuscaPessoa.itemSelecionado}` is also a `String`, then you should just use `itemValue="#{pessoa.value}"` and remove the `Converter` altogether.

#### See also:

- [PrimeFaces showcase: `<p:autoComplete>` with POJO](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf)
- [Can I use omnifaces generic converter in primefaces autocomplete component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631837/can-i-use-omnifaces-generic-converter-in-primefaces-autocomplete-component/)
- [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-for-null-converter)

Comment: I think your last sentence does not work because for some reason ever, when you reload/commit the widget the shown label wants to be builded from the itemValue and this breaks the idea to put just the string into the itemValue and so in the value attribute. You can have different Strings in as value and label and this works totally fine with a converter, but in the moment you use the var attribute this goes down the river. If you do not need the var this works, but if you need the var to "beautify" your label with columns and stuff my ideas end, did not get this running.

Comment: See 2nd "See also" link how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

A generic Converter which you can use for Primefaces Auto-completes and all other purposes:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
        for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Makky Thanks for the generic converter code its a good idea and very useful. I can change    
Map<Object, String> entities to List also if I want to right??

Comment: erm, the entities-map would fill up over the time? when does it get cleaned up? (=memory hog)

Comment: @Bernhard What would you suggest to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and the author's comment at [Primefaces autocomplete with POJO and String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966873/primefaces-autocomplete-with-pojo-and-string-value) gave me the hint to find the source of the problem in my case.

### Overview

The problem is that `value=#{objectValue}` is of type `String` but the method referenced in `completeMethod` is returning a `List<Object>`.

### The Design

I have the following POJOs (simplified):

```
public class CollaboratorGroup {
   private String groupId;

   private String groupName;

   private Collaborator piUserId;

   ...
}
```

and

```
public class Collaborator {
   private String userId;

   private String fullName;

   private String groupId;
   ...
}
```

Does not matter whether this is a useful design. I just want to address the issue.

The following `p:autoComplete` (simplified):

```
<p:autoComplete var="group"
    itemLabel="#{group.groupId}"
    itemValue="#{group.groupId}"
    completeMethod="#{bean.completeGroup}"
    value="#{collaborator.groupId}">
    <f:facet name="itemtip">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{group.groupId}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{group.groupName}" />
            <h:outputText value="PI" />
            <h:outputText value="#{group.piUserId.fullName}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
</p:autoComplete>
```

will throw `The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'groupId'`. When I change to `itemLabel=#{group}`, I will see the groupId `CG00255` in the input field but many of `org.coadd.sharedresources.model.CollaboratorGroup@...` in the dropdown list. If I select one of these, this `toString()` value is set to Collaborator.groupId which is not desired.

### The Problem's Source

I feed the `p:autoComplete` with a `List<CollaboratorGroup>` while `Collaborator.groupId` is a `String` and `itemLabel` is used to "format" both, the `String groupId` set as `value="#{collaborator.groupId}"` and the `CollaboratorGroup` that comes from the `List`, generated by `completeMethod="#{bean.completeGroup}"`.

### Possible Solutions

1. You could adjust the `Model` by changing the member `groupId` to `CollaboratorGroup` in `Collaborator` if it does not destroy your design. In this case, especially as `CollaboratorGroup` has the member `Collaborator piUserId`.
2. You could just fill the `p:autoComplete` with `List<String> groupIdList` but in this case you have to find a different solution for the `itemtip`.
3. A very quick solution is to use `itemLabel="#{group.class.simpleName eq 'String' ? group : group.groupId}"` as mentionned at [Primefaces autocomplete with POJO and String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966873/primefaces-autocomplete-with-pojo-and-string-value).

   - Problems

     - You have to care about `NullPointerExceptions`.
     - You fill up your `View` with logic.
     - It is not a very flexible or dynamic design.
4. Implement 3. in a bean method `itemLabel="#{bean.printGroupId(group)}"` where you have full control over the logic. This is what I did.

   ```
   public String printGroupId(Object group) {
       if (group == null) return null;
       return (group instanceof String) ? (String) group : (group instanceof CollaboratorGroup) ? ((CollaboratorGroup) group).getGroupId() : null;
   }
   ```

   (Not the best, just to give you an idea.)

Answer (score 1):

One more easiest way to achieve this by:
overriding the **toString()** method in Pessoa Pojo class.
This toString() **should only return Label** that you want to display.
If you use this method then there is **NO NEED for converter**.

For example:

```
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{

private String value;
private String label;

//Setter and getters

@Override
public void toString(){
return label;
}

}
```

Then you can use:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{modeloPopupBuscaPessoa.itemSelecionado}"
                completeMethod="#{controladorSugestaoPessoa.atualizarSugestoes}"
                var="pessoa" itemLabel="#{pessoa}" itemValue="#{pessoa.value}"/>
```

This is the way i'm currently using and working well.

Comment: Use converter which is a recommend.

Comment: @Makky : Converter will convert Object to String right?? By default in java if a object needs to be displayed then JVM will invoke toString() method. That's what I'm doing in toString(). Both methods yields same results only. Tanks and sure I'll use Converter as its recommended

Comment: I have posted a generic converter which would work for any object.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
 ItemBean itemBean = (ItemBean) elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "itemBean");
 for(Item item : itemBean.getItems()){
     if(item.getId().getItemCode().equals(value)){
         return item;
     }
 }
```

Comment: in Conver Class ,Public  Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {  in this method write down the  above logic and get the list of items from bean ,definatley you will get it

Comment: Please add this to your answer, you can edit it. And please add some more explanation on why this works and is a better answer than what is already posted