# primefaces autocomplete with pojo

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces, pojo

I read on SO some QA about the same component, but I feel I'm missing something, because I am one step behind.
I can't even make the page open when using the primefaces autocomplete component in it.
The snippet for it is:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{indirizzoCtrl.selectedCodiceNazione}"  
            completeMethod="#{indirizzoCtrl.completeNazione}"  
            var="nazione" itemLabel="#{nazione.nome}"   
            itemValue="#{nazione.codiceNazione}" />
```

Nazione is a Pojo class where `CodiceNazione` and `Nome are` two String field (with getter and setter for sure). `completeNazione` is a method on the ManagedBean that returns `List<Nazione>`.
Looking at BalusC explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7653775/333223), it seems to me that i don't need any converter involved, because both itemValue and value attributes are mapped to string property.
Anyway, when I just open the page containing this autocomplete snippet, it crashes with this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /Cliente/Indirizzo.xhtml @23,56 itemValue="#{nazione.codiceNazione}": itemValue="#{nazione.codiceNazione}": Property 'codiceNazione' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Why this is happening? I really can't get it. The method completeNazione hasn't even called yet, so it shouldn't know any `Nazione` yet.
What's wrong with it?

***Edited:***
Following the suggestion, I tried to add a converter, but I still get the same error.
Here's my converter:

```
    public class NazioneConverter implements Converter {

    final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NazioneConverter.class);

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value.trim().equals("")) {  
            return null;  
        } else {  
            try {  
                IndirizzoRepository ir = new IndirizzoRepository();
                List<Nazione> nazioni = ir.getNazioneByName(value);
                if (nazioni.size()==1) return nazioni.get(0);
                else throw new Exception();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                String msg = "Errore di conversione";
                log.error(msg, e);
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, "Non è una nazione conosciuta"));  
            }  
        }          
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {  
            return "";  
        } else {  
            return String.valueOf(((Nazione) value).getNome());  
        } 
    }

}
```

now the component in the view looks like:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{indirizzoCtrl.indirizzo.nazione.codiceNazione}"  
            completeMethod="#{indirizzoCtrl.completeNazione}"  
            var="nazione" itemLabel="#{nazione.nome}" converter="#{nazioneConverter}"
            itemValue="#{nazione.codiceNazione}" forceSelection="true"  />
```

But still don't working. The converter is not even invoked: I registered it in my faces-config.xml file.
I also tried itemValue="#{nazione}" as in the primefaces showcase but the problem became the `ItemLabel` attribute, mapped to `nazione.nome`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What PF version? Do other PF components work fine in the same view?

Comment: @BalusC: version 2.2, and everything else works just fine

Comment: What's the error message after adding the converter?

Comment: @gurung: exactly the same. If I write `itemValue="#{nazione.codiceNazione}"` then the error message is exactly the same. If I change it to `itemValue="#{nazione}"` then the exact same error is thrown, but referred to `itemLabel="#{nazione.nome}"`.
In pratice it cannot pull the property out of `nazione` object.

Comment: @themarcuz Has anybody figured out this issue? I have the exact same problem. I've been studying the matter and I do not think that we need a converter, since the value field of autoComplete is a String, not POJOs. I would really appreciate an answer!

Answer (score 1):

### This worked for me:

```
//Converter
@FacesConverter(value="MarcaConverter")
public class MarcaConverter implements Converter{
    MarcaDAO marcaDAO;
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext contet, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value==null || value.equals(""))
            return null;
        try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
            return marcaDAO.findMarcaById(id);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Marca no válida", ""));
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext contet, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if(value==null || value.equals(""))
            return null;
        return String.valueOf(((Marca)value).getCodigoMarca());
    }
}




//--------------------------------------
//Bean
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBeans implements Serializable{
    private Marca marca;
    ...
    public Marca getMarca(){
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(Marca m){
        marca=m;
    }
    ...
    public List<Marca> obtenerMarcasVehiculos(String s) {
        List<Marca> marcas,smarcas=new ArrayList<Marca>();
        try{
            marcas= marcaDAO.findAllMarcas();
            if(s.trim().equals("")) return marcas;
            for(Marca m:marcas)
                if (m.getNombreMarca().toString().contains(s) || m.getNombreMarca().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
                    smarcas.add(m);
                }
            return smarcas;
        }catch(Exception e){
            //JsfUtil.showFacesMsg(e,"Error al obtener las marcas de veh&iacute;culos","",FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN);
            e.printStackTrace();
            JsfUtil.lanzarException(e);
            return null;
        }
    }


//-----------------------------------------
//*.xhtml page
...
    <p:autoComplete 
       id="cbxMarca" value="#{myBean.marca}" size="40"
       converter="MarcaConverter"
       completeMethod="#{myBean.obtenerMarcasVehiculos}"
       var="m" itemLabel="#{m.nombreMarca}" itemValue="#{m}"
       forceSelection="true" dropdown="true"
       required="true" scrollHeight="200">
    </p:autoComplete>
...

//-----------------------------------------
//Class Marca
public class Marca implements Serializable{
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer codigoMarca;
    private String nombreMarca;
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the user guide? http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html

I must say I have never used the autocomplete with pojo but from what I've read in the user guide, Çağatay Çivici says there:

> Note that when working with pojos, you need to plug-in your own converter.

[Here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf) you can find out that a converter (`PlayerConverter`) is implemented even if `player.name` and of the other props are Strings.

I admit this is interesting and I'll do some research but I don't have the necessary time right now...

Comment: I read the user guide, but reading this post from BalusC
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7653775/333223
I understood that I could avoid a converter in my case... but maybe I misunderstood something...

Comment: @themarcuz add a simple converter and see for yourself...You can't learn programming without practice!

Comment: for sure I'll do it... I'm just busy with another task right now, but in a few hour I'll try to get it works as suggested

Comment: @themarcuz Good for you! Let me know of the results. I'll even try myself but maybe tomorrow...

Comment: Added new info... I tried with the converter, but nothing changes :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the `itemValue` from `itemValue="#{nazione.codiceNazione}"` to `itemValue="#{nazione}"` in autoComplete.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`converter="#{nazioneConverter}"` to `converter="nazioneConverter"` in `autocomplete`