# Can I use omnifaces generic converter in primefaces autocomplete component?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I am trying to use [Omnifaces generic Converter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) in [Primefaces autocomplete component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf)
Like this :

```
<p:dataTable id="transactiondetailsid" value="# {stockTransactionsBean.stkTransHeader.stkTransDetailsList}" var="stkTransDet"  rowIndexVar="rowIndex">  

      <p:column>  
       <f:facet name="header">  
     <h:outputText value="Item Code" />  
    </f:facet>  

 <p:autoComplete id="dd" dropdown="true" autocomplete="true" 
   value="#{stkTransDet.item}" var="i" itemLabel="#{i.itemnamee}" 
   itemValue="#{i}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
   completeMethod="#{stockTransactionsBean.completeItems}" forceSelection="true" 
   scrollHeight="250" minQueryLength="3" maxResults="30" queryDelay="1000" size="20" /> 

     </p:column>  
      </p:dataTable>
```

But its not working because **omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter** depend on 
**f:selectItems** tag which can not be used inside **p:autoComplete**

Any suggestions or work arounds ????

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the other converter specifically designed for this purpose, the [`ListConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter).

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{bean.selectedItem}" completeMethod="#{bean.completeItems}">
    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{bean.availableItems}"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

```
private String selectedItem; // +getter+setter
private List<String> availableItems; // +getter

public List<String> completeItems(String query) {
    availableItems = someService.search(query);
    return availableItems;
}
```

Comment: it would be helpful to have this example at the showcase: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter