# issue with ajax in primefaces "selectOneMenu"

Tags: ajax, jsf, netbeans, primefaces, entity

index.xhtml

```
        <p:selectOneMenu id="d2" value="#{mainManageBean.areaSelected}"  >
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select one" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{mainManageBean.areaList}" var="area"
                           itemValue="#{area.id}" itemLabel="#{area.name}"/> 
        <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{mainManageBean.changeAreaSelect()}" update="hi"  /> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

When i have value set like this "mainManageBean.areaSelected" where areaSelected is entity from database

```
private Area areaSelected;
```

the ajax event dont work,
but when i change it to something like this "mainManageBean.s1menu" where this "s1menu" is just a normal String ajax event work fine.

What is the reason of that and how to fix it?

## Edit

this is my buged converter:

```
@FacesConverter
public class areaConverter implements Converter{


@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

    // here i have problem value is id of entity and have no idea how to get this entity form this id

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

// works fine value = Area entity
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
   if (value == null || value.equals("")) {  
        return "";  
    } else {  
        return String.valueOf(((Area) value).getId());  
    } 
}    
}
```

Have problem with getAsObject, i have this value as id but cant get entity from it. Normaly i would use AreaFacade.find(id) but i cant use there @EJB to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `<f:selectItem itemValue>` is wrong. It should represent exactly the same type as `<p:selectOneMenu value>`, which is thus `Area`. Replace `itemValue="#{area.id}"` by `itemValue="#{area}"`. You indeed need a `Converter` for this.

As to your problem with the converter,

> *Have problem with getAsObject, i have this value as id but cant get entity from it. Normaly i would use AreaFacade.find(id) but i cant use there @EJB to get it.*

you have 2 options:

1. Make it a `@ManagedBean @RequestScoped` instead of `@FacesConverter` and reference it as `converter="#{areaConverter}"` instead of `converter="areaConverter"`.
2. Install [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) >= 1.6. It adds full transparent support for `@EJB` inside `@FacesConverter` without any additional configuration or annotations.

If you go the OmniFaces path anyway, then you could also just throw away your custom converter altogether and go for its builtin `SelectItems(Index)Converter` without the need to create any custom converter for `itemValue="#{area}"`.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
```

#### See also:

- [CDI Injection into a FacesConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter)

Comment: I used this 1st option and i think its work fine.
But still this ajax event dont want to work with entity (with normal string work fine).

Comment: You're welcome. As to the new problem, it's helpful if you elaborate the problem in developer's perspective instead of enduser's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

**As per comment from Kuba**

```
<f:selectItems value="#{mainManageBean.areaList}" var="area"
                           itemValue="#{area.id}" itemLabel="#{area.name}"/>
```

change itemValue as

```
<f:selectItems value="#{mainManageBean.areaList}" var="area"
                           itemValue="#{area}" itemLabel="#{area.name}"/>
```

**Update:**

The other thing it could be the converter. My suggestion is to use the SelectItemsConverter from Onmnifaces.

[Omnifaces select item converter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter)

Comment: @Kuba didn't see your comment ! Sorry

Comment: @Kuba I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set an Entity with value of ID, I assume Integer or String? The reason why ajax does not fire is because `event="valueChange"` does not occur. If you tried to submit this form without ajax you would get a sweet ClassCastException. As I mentioned in my comment and Makky in his answer, change itemValue to:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="d2" value="#{mainManageBean.areaSelected}"  >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select one" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{mainManageBean.areaList}" var="area"
                       itemValue="#{area}" itemLabel="#{area.name}"/> 
    <p:ajax listener="#{mainManageBean.changeAreaSelect()}" update="hi" process="@this /> 
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Sorry but this notching change.

Comment: I think it can be problem with converter.

Comment: it might, but what exactly does not work? event does not fire? did you try to set a breakpoint at `mainManageBean.changeAreaSelect()`? no network activity?

Comment: if you by any chance use OmniFaces, take a look at this [converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149109/jsf-selectonemenu-generic-converter-issue)

Comment: @Kuba I can't believe what's going ? I just answered the same thing and you left that as a comment

Comment: my mistake, forgot to delete the comment after writing the answer.

Comment: @Makky oh, you mean the converter thing? coincidence i guess :-)

Comment: Yes.I meant the converter thing. Spooky.