# How to use selectOneMenu without converter?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, menuitem, selectonemenu

I'm using `selectOneMenu` for displaying some pictures and Strings, the pictures is for displaying purposes only i have (i.e. i have nothing to do with them on submitting) i want only to set the string next to the image, i have a conflict in setting the `itemValue` of the `f:selectItems` to the String required, when i do that the images doesn't appear at all, in a word i want to only submit the value of the string in the chosen `selectItem` without using converter:

JSF Code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="SkinChooser" value="#{personBean.ObjectDTO.personDescription.skin}"
        panelStyle="width:150px" effect="fade" var="s"
        style="width:160px" converter="#{personBean.converter}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{missedPersonBean.selectedSkins}"
        var="skin" itemLabel="#{skin.skinType}" itemValue="#{skin}" />
                <p:column>
                      <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/skin/#{s.skinPhoto}"
                                width="40" height="50" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column> 
                      #{s.skinType}  
                </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Skin.Java

```
public class Skin {
String skinPhoto;
String skinType;

public Skin() {
}

public Skin(String photo, String type) {
    this.skinPhoto = photo;
    this.skinType = type;
}

public String getSkinPhoto() {
    return skinPhoto;
}

public void setSkinPhoto(String skinPhoto) {
    this.skinPhoto = skinPhoto;
}

public String getSkinType() {
    return skinType;
}

public void setSkinType(String skinType) {
    this.skinType = skinType;
    }
}
```

personBean.Java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "personBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ReportPerson {
private Skin skin;
private static List<Skin> selectedSkins;


static {
System.err.println("Array is filled");
selectedSkins = new ArrayList<Skin>();
selectedSkins.add(new Skin("1", "Pale white"));
selectedSkins.add(new Skin("2", "Fair white"));
selectedSkins.add(new Skin("3", "Light brown"));
selectedSkins.add(new Skin("4", "Moderate brown"));
selectedSkins.add(new Skin("5", "Dark brown"));
selectedSkins.add(new Skin("6", "Deeply pigmented"));
System.err.println("Finished Filling");

}

public List<Skin> getSelectedSkins() {
return selectedSkins;
}

 public void setSelectedSkins(List<Skin> selectedSkins) {
 this.selectedSkins = selectedSkins;
 }

public Skin getSkin() {
return skin;
 }

 public void setSkin(Skin skin) {this.skin = skin;}

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF 2 : Selection / Combo-box with/without conversion strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/jsf-2-selection-combo-box-with-without-conversion-strategy)

Comment: Use a `String` field as your `itemValue` in `<f:selectItems>` and a `String` field in `value` of `<p:selectOneMenu>`.