# UISelectMany on a List<T> causes java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to T

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, classcastexception, selectmanycheckbox

I am using [`<p:selectCheckboxMenu>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml) on a `List<Long>`:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

```
private List<Long> selectedItems;
private Map<String, Long> availableItems;
```

When submitting the form and looping over the selected items as below,

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
    Long id = selectedItems.get(i);
    // ...
}
```

Then I get a class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.example.Bean.submit(Bean.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 27 more
```

The same problem occurs with `<p:selectManyCheckbox>`, `<p:selectManyMenu>`, `<h:selectManyMenu>`, etc. All multiple-selection components basically. It works fine in `<p:selectOneMenu>` and all other single-selection components on a single value `Long` property.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: can you share the content of your list because this code does not seem to prone to this exception

Comment: @ankit see my post. I edit and add picture

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the following facts:

1. Java generics are compiletime syntactic sugar and completely absent during runtime.
2. EL expressions runs during runtime and not during compiletime.
3. HTTP request parameters are [obtained](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) as `String`s.

Logical consequence is: EL doesn't see any generic type information. EL doesn't see a `List<Long>`, but a `List`. So, when you don't explicitly specify a converter, EL will after obtaining the submitted value as `String` set it unmodified in the `List` by [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) means. When you attempt to cast it to `Long` afterwards during runtime, you'll obviously face a `ClassCastException`.

The solution is simple: explicitly specify a converter for `String` to `Long`. You can use the JSF builtin [`LongConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/LongConverter.html) for this which has the converter ID [`javax.faces.Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.LongConverter.CONVERTER_ID). Other builtin converters are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/package-summary.html).

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu ... converter="javax.faces.Long">
```

Another solution without the need to explicitly specify the converter is to change `List<T>` type to a `T[]`. This way the EL will see the `Long` typed array and thus perform automatic conversion. But this possibly requires changes elsewhere in the model which may not be desirable.

```
private Long[] selectedItems;
```

In case you're using a complex object (javabean, entity, POJO, etc) as select item value instead of a standard type like `Long` for which JSF has builtin converters, then the same rules also apply. You only need to create a custom `Converter` and explicitly specify it in input component's `converter` attribute, or rely on `forClass` if you can use `T[]`. How to create such a converter is elaborated in [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-com-example-warehousecafebabe-for-null-conver).

Comment: Hit ...I was looking one for answer..i didn't know that we can do it in JSF itself.

Comment: Saddly, only first workaround works well, looks like primefaces create a `List` and cant convert to `array` since `Value not valid` validation error is throw

Comment: The `Validation Error: Value is not valid` is elaborated here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9069379