# p:selectManyMenu and @FacesConverter(forClass = Clazz.class)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters, selectmanymenu

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="colourList"
                  var="color"
                  value="#{testBean.selectedColours}"
                  converter="#{colourConverter}"
                  showCheckbox="true"
                  required="true"
                  label="Colour"
                  style="overflow: auto; width: 317px; background-color: white; max-height: 200px;">

    <f:selectItems var="colour"
                   value="#{testBean.colours}"
                   itemLabel="#{colour.colourHex}"
                   itemValue="#{colour}"/>
    <p:column>
        <span style="display: inline-block; width: 275px; height: 20px; background-color:\##{color.colourHex}; border: 1px solid black;"
              title="Name: #{color.colourName} | Hex: #{color.colourHex}" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{testBean.action}"/>
```

<sub>CSS is left intact, if someone may want to put the example into practice. It will display three basic colours (RGB) with check boxes in front of them as follows.</sub>

[image]

The managed bean :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private DataStore dataStore;
    private List<Colour> colours; //Getter & setter.
    private List<Colour> selectedColours; //Getter & setter.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        colours = dataStore.getColours();
    }

    public void action() {
        for (Colour colour : selectedColours) {
            System.out.println("colourName : "
                    + colour.getColourName()
                    + " : colourHex : "
                    + colour.getColourHex());
        }
    }
}
```

If the `converter="#{colourConverter}"` attribute is removed from `<p:selectManyMenu>`, then it causes a `java.lang.ClassCastException` to be thrown in the `action()` method even though the converter is decorated with `@FacesConverter(forClass = Colour.class)`.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.Colour
```

It appears that it is the generic type eraser problem (the generic type parameter of `List<Colour>` is removed at run time so that it turns into an untyped `List`).

`Colour[]` should then work but the `action()` method itself was not invoked, when attempted.

What is the exact reason why it requires an explicit mention of a converter?

---

**Additional :**

The converter :

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = Colour.class)
public class ColourConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private DataStore dataStore;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            long parsedValue = Long.parseLong(value);

            if (parsedValue <= 0) {
                throw new ConverterException("FacesMessage");
            }

            Colour entity = dataStore.findColourById(parsedValue);

            if (entity == null) {
                throw new ConverterException("FacesMessage");
            }
            return entity;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException("FacesMessage", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (!(value instanceof Colour)) {
            throw new ConverterException("Message");
        }

        Long id = ((Colour) value).getColourId();
        return id != null ? id.toString() : "";
    }
}
```

The application scoped bean where the `List<Colour>` is maintained.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataStore {

    private List<Colour> colours;

    public DataStore() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        colours = new ArrayList<>();

        Colour colour = new Colour();
        colour.setColourId(1L);
        colour.setColourName("Red");
        colour.setColourHex("FF0000");
        colours.add(colour);

        colour = new Colour();
        colour.setColourId(3L);
        colour.setColourName("Green");
        colour.setColourHex("008000");
        colours.add(colour);

        colour = new Colour();
        colour.setColourId(2L);
        colour.setColourName("Blue");
        colour.setColourHex("0000FF");
        colours.add(colour);
    }

    public Colour findColourById(Long id) {
        for (Colour colour : colours) {
            if (colour.getColourId().equals(id)) {
                return colour;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public List<Colour> getColours() {
        return colours;
    }
}
```

The domain model class :

```
public class Colour implements Serializable {

    private Long colourId;
    private String colourName;
    private String colourHex;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Colour() {}

    public Long getColourId() {
        return colourId;
    }

    public void setColourId(Long colourId) {
        this.colourId = colourId;
    }

    public String getColourName() {
        return colourName;
    }

    public void setColourName(String colourName) {
        this.colourName = colourName;
    }

    public String getColourHex() {
        return colourHex;
    }

    public void setColourHex(String colourHex) {
        this.colourHex = colourHex;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(getColourId());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (!(that instanceof Colour)) {
            return false;
        }

        return this == that || Objects.equals(getColourId(), ((Colour) that).getColourId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s[colourId=%d]", getClass().getCanonicalName(), getColourId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872633/pselectcheckboxmenu-on-a-listlong-causes-java-lang-classcastexception-java/

Comment: Yes. Except using `Colour[]` did not work for me. The `action()` method itself was not invoked.

Comment: So a conversion/validation error occurred? Note that `@Named` and `@FacesConverter` are mutually exclusive (i.e. 2 separate instances are created, one managed by CDI and other managed by JSF). Unless you're using OmniFaces, `@Inject` won't work in the JSF-managed `@FacesConverter` instance.

Comment: `@Inject` works thanks to OmniFaces on the class-path. I removed the CDI  designation from the converter. Upon submit, it passes through the converter. There is no conversion error (`required="true"` was also dropped) but it does not reach the `action()` method, when `List<Colour>` is turned into `Colour[]`.

Comment: The `getAsObject()` method receives a String value like `com.example.Colour[colourId=3]`, when `Colour[]` is used in the bean. It should instead receive `3`. Hence, it causes a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. Since this exception was being caught and I removed `FacesMessage`s as well, It was not directly visible from the browser. Why does it do `Colour#toString()` directly, when `Colour[]` is used?

Comment: This is not the expected behavior. I'd have to take a look myself.

Comment: Indeed, the `<p:selectManyMenu>` doesn't locate/invoke the converter by class during rendering. The `<h:selectManyMenu>` however does. Must be a bug in its renderer.

Comment: Who is the daemon/demon downvoter? First time in more than three years, saying something about a negative vote. Many amateur and immature people (even though they achieved a university level) everyday cast fraud votes to their own posts using clone accounts and/or on behalf of their colleagues. Go cast your negative votes to such poor quality posts as many as you can. Please don't disturb me without any sufficient cause. I am already disturbed enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is two-fold.

First problem is that EL can't determine the model value type, because the generic type information is lost during runtime. It basically becomes `Object.class`. You basically need to replace `List<Colour>` by `Colour[]`. This is in detail answered in this question: [UISelectMany on a List<T> causes java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872633/pselectcheckboxmenu-on-a-listlong-causes-java-lang-classcastexception-java/).

Second problem is that PrimeFaces [`InputRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2/org/primefaces/renderkit/InputRenderer.java#InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Cjavax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) has the bug that it doesn't take into account with array types before locating the converter. Line numbers below match 5.2

```
156    protected Converter findImplicitConverter(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
157        ValueExpression ve = component.getValueExpression("value");
158
159        if(ve != null) {
160            Class<?> valueType = ve.getType(context.getELContext());
161                
162            if(valueType != null)
163                return context.getApplication().createConverter(valueType);
164        }
165
166        return null;
167    }
```

In your specific case, the `valueType` is `Colour[].class` instead of `Colour.class`. This explians why it couldn't locate the converter associated with `Colour.class`. Before creating the converter, it should have checked if the `valueType` is an [array type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--) and if so then extract the [component type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--) from it.

```
if (valueType.isArray()) {
    valueType = valueType.getComponentType();
}
```

You'd best report this as a bug to PrimeFaces guys along with the fact that it works fine in standard components like `<h:selectManyMenu>`. In the meanwhile, your best bet is to just explicitly register the converter.