<o:validateBean>: turns List<DemoData> into List<String>?
I want to use <o:validateBean> to validate my bean at the class level. The bean is:
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class ValidateClassLevelBean implements Serializable {
   ...
   @Inject
   private Conversation con;

   @Min(value = 2)
   @Max(value = 5)
   private int objectCount;

   @Valid
   private List<DemoData> listData;

   public String reInit() {
     if (!con.isTransient()) {con.end();}
     con.begin();

     listData = new ArrayList<>(objectCount);
     for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) {
        listData.add(new DemoData("bbb", 3));
     }
    
    return "validProduct_2";
  }

  public String action() {
    for (DemoData d : listData) {
      logger.info("[listData: <" + d.toString() + ">]");
    }
    con.end();
    return "index";
  }
  ...
}

The Facelet looks like this:
 <h:form id="classLevelFormCustomCopier">
  ...
  <table>
   <ui:repeat value="#{validateClassLevelBean.listData}" var="data" varStatus="loop">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <h:inputText id="dataInput"
                   value="#{validateClassLevelBean.listData[loop.index]}"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </ui:repeat>
  </table>

  <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{validateClassLevelBean.action}">
   <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
  </h:commandButton>

  <o:validateBean value="#{validateClassLevelBean}"
                  validationGroups="de.test.wholebeanvalidation.validProduct.DemoDataGroup" />

The DemoData is nothing special (a forClass-Converter exists):
@ValidDemoData(groups = DemoDataGroup.class)
public class DemoData implements Serializable {
  ...
  private String strData;
  private int intData;
  
  public DemoData() {
    this.strData ="";
    this.intData=0;
  }

  public DemoData(DemoData d) {
    this.strData =d.getStrData();
    this.intData = d.getIntData();
  }
  ...
}

The validation constraint annotation:
@Constraint(validatedBy = { DemoDataValidator.class })
@Documented
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidDemoData {
  String message() default "Invalid product";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

The Validator:
public class DemoDataValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDemoData, ValidateClassLevelBean> {
  ...
  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidDemoData constraintAnnotation) {
    logger.info("[ init ]");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(ValidateClassLevelBean value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
     ...
     return true;
  }
}

Droped the copier="..." and the Exception is:
[2024-07-27T18:02:30.870+0200] [Payara 6.2024.1] [SCHWERWIEGEND] [] [org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateBean] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(3)] [timeMillis: 1722096150870] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception occured while doing validation.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.setBeanPropertyWithDefaultValue(Reflection.java:410)
at org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.getBeanProperty(Reflection.java:397)
at org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.getBase(Reflection.java:336)
at org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.setBeanProperties(Reflection.java:314)
at org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateBean$3.invoke(ValidateBean.java:456)
at org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateBean$ValidateBeanCallback.run(ValidateBean.java:751)
at org.omnifaces.util.Events.lambda$wrap$1(Events.java:334)
at org.omnifaces.util.Events$4.afterPhase(Events.java:370)
at org.omnifaces.eventlistener.CallbackPhaseListener.afterPhase(CallbackPhaseListener.java:69)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:148)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:691)
at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1554)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:239)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:190)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)


After cleaning up the code a bit, I can't reproduce it using OmniFaces 4.4. I only removed @ValidProduct from managed bean class as that actually belongs on DemoData class (see also showcase example). I didn't use a copier as that's not required in this case. When I keep the @ValidProduct incorrectly on the manage bean I get a different exception HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.ValidProduct' validating type 'com.example.ValidateClassLevelBean'..

Thanks for your effort on this case. I thought the @ValidXyz(groups=...)-Annotation belongs to the class to be validated, Product in the showcase example, the whole backing bean in my case (if this example works, I will add more fields to the backingbean to validate the combination of the fields).

Validation constraint annotation should be put on a model class not a controller class.

Updated my code and the original Posting.

(a forClass-Converter exists): Oh wow, so the DemoData class is actually handled as a property instead of as a bean/entity/dto/vo? That was unexpected. I initially expected you just showed an oversimplified xhtml example in the initial question whereby the bean's properties aren't at all referenced, while I was using the same xhtml example at the showcase as hinted in the initial question whereby the bean's properties were correctly referenced. This use case has never been considered/analyzed while designing the o:validateBean. I'll need to take a second look here.

I'm not sure anymore, if this issue is related to <o:validateBean>. When I drop all validation and focus just on gathering the data via <ui:repeat> in conjunction with a forClass Converter, the forClass converter is not called for the list elements and I end up with the "String instead of DemoData" situation. Maybe this is more a mojarra issue than an OmniFaces issue.

You're right, it works when the converter is explicitly registered on h:inputText. This is not a Mojarra/Faces issue, this is EL/generics issue. Here's a closely related Q&A on the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19872633


a forClass-Converter exists

The observable problem is in the end not caused by <o:validateBean>. It's caused by erasure of generic type and EL (those #{..} things) in its current version being unable to deal with it. While setting a new item in a List, EL doesn't know what the generic type of the list is and therefore assumes the default of String.
You can solve this by explicitly registering the converter on the input component, or, as you discovered, by using a plain array instead of a List.
<h:inputText id="dataInput"
             value="#{validateClassLevelBean.listData[loop.index]}"
             converter="yourDemoDataConverter" />


I wonder, that this fact is not mentioned in the books and docs. Thanks once again for your effort on this case.

FYI: I noticed that <o:validateBean showMessageFor="@violating"> didn't work in this specific use case, so I fixed it: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/827. You may find the associated integration test helpful as well: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/f51fccf4733089ae2e761af814a2d0767d43b547

In my opinion, such an example for validation is worth to be published more prominent.  Thanks.
