# custom converter - dependent selectonemenu not populated

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, selectonemenu

I have tried to set up two selectOneMenus where the first selects an object, and in the second, one of five object parameters can be selected. For this, I have built a custom converter, and "id" should be passed from the first selectOneMenu to uniqely identify the object for the second menu. On page load, the `getAsString` method is called and iterated through all items of the first menu. On selecting an item, `getAsObject` is called, and the correct `id` is used and the correct `Question` is returned. But: the second menu is not populated at all. What did I miss? Help appreciated, I'm still learning this.

Here is the first selectOneMenu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu converter="answerDeliverer">
    <f:selectItems value="#{questionBean.list}" var="question" itemValue="#{question}" itemLabel="#{question.text}"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" render="answers"></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And the second:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="answers">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{question.a1}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="#{question.a2}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="#{question.a3}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="#{question.a4}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="#{question.a5}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And the converter:

```
@ManagedBean (name = "answerDeliverer")
@RequestScoped
public class answerDeliverer implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private QuestionDAO questionDAO;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
        return questionDAO.get(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Question) {
        return ((Question) o).getId();
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
        return ((String) o);
    } else throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(o + " is not a valid Question or id"));
    //just so I can try either question or question.id as itemValues
}

}
```

The error log is empty, only on startup I get several warnings of this type:

```
Unknow type constant pool 18 at position 7
Nov 03, 2015 1:17:10 PM com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo containsAnnotation
```

After hours and hours of debugging, I'm stuck now. I can conclude the following:

- The `answerDeliverer` seems to work. On selection, `getAsObject` fetches the correct `question` from the DB
- XHR is registered in browser debug mode on every selection with a "200 OK" server answer
- There is no other error in the log
- I seem to have something wrong with bringing the `question` into the scope of the second selectOneMenu. `Question` is not a `ManagedBean`, and in my `QuestionBean`, `private Question question = new Question()`, so, could it be that no matter what I do in the first selectOneMenu, the second always generates a new instance and doesn't care about what I did before? And thus erases any `question` I had before? How could I avoid that?

I'm using Mojarra-2.2.1 on Tomcat 8. Also tried to go with OmniFaces, but got stuck in an infinite loop of debugging the setup there before giving up on that.

I'll add my `Question` POJO and the Bean if that helps any.

```
public class Question implements Serializable {
    private String text;
    private String a1 = Constants.defaulta1;
    private String a2 = Constants.defaulta2;
    private String a3 = Constants.defaulta3;
    private String a4 = Constants.defaulta4;
    private String a5 = Constants.defaulta5;
    private String id;
    private String nodeid;
    //getters and setters
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass() && id != null)
                ? id.equals(((Question) other).id)
                : (other == this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (id != null)
                ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
                : super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and the `QuestionBean`:

```
@ManagedBean (name="questionBean")
@ViewScoped
public class QuestionBean implements Serializable {
    private List<Question> list;

    //this was for a CRUD page; I deleted the other irrelevant code
    private Question question = new Question();
    private boolean edited;

    @EJB
    private QuestionDAO questionDAO;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = questionDAO.getAll();
    }

    public List<Question> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

}
```

Comment: Apart from the actual question : `<f:ajax>` does not have attributes like `ajaxSingle` and `update`. The private member `Question` in the converter is completely unnecessary. Get rid of it. `ConverterException` needs to be thrown basically when a corresponding `Object`, for some reasons, cannot be constructed based on the (`String`) value given. How do you confirm that `getAsObject()` is not invoked? It will be invoked upon submission - when an `Object` is to be constructed based on a `String` value. What is returned by `questionDAO.get(Integer.valueOf(s))`? (It is supposed to be `Question`).

Comment: Is the ajax request sent or not? I.e. the form is successfully submitted with ajax and you're seeing a XHR request in browser's HTTP traffic monitor?

Comment: @BalusC I just took a look: no, it's not sent!! did I forget something here?

Comment: Well then this duplicates #1 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: thanks @BalusC! Now XHR is sent, and gets 200 OK response. getAsObject is invoked, too! But the second menu isn't populated. Server logs are empty, no errors. Strangely, getAsObject now gets called on choosing an item with the correct id, and the correct `Question` is then returned. But after that, it loops through *all* items again, and then another time sparing the last item!?!

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6848970 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4734580

Comment: I tried to setup another even simpler test page according to this, but failed in the same way that the converter works and the second menu stays empty; I'm pretty frustrated now. I added my POJO and bean above now. No errors on log. Just seems like my `question` instance disappears when it should be there in the second menu.

Comment: I suggest to put this all aside and carefully read the links in previous comment and play around with the examples found therein as long as until you get the "Aha-Erlebnis" ;)

Comment: thanks for cheering me up ;)   I will, and I'll try to have someone "look over my shoulder" as I think that I'm stuck in my pattern of thinking and need some fresh air