# SelectOneMenu valuchangeListener event.getNewValue() always returns null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I have a valuechangelistener for selectOneMenu but event.getNewValue() always returns null

```
                   <p:selectOneMenu value="#{localeBean.selectedLocale}"
                    converter="locale" onchange="submit();" effect="fade" var="loc"
                    filterMatchMode="startsWith" styleClass="flagDisplay" valueChangeListener="#{localeBean.selectedLocaleValue}"
                    >        
                    <f:selectItems value="#{localeBean.locales}" var="locale"
                        itemLabel="#{locale.name}" itemValue="#{locale}" />

                    <p:column>
                        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/#{loc.photo}">   <h:outputText value="#{loc.name}" styleClass="welcome" style="margin:0px!important;padding:1px;"/></p:graphicImage>

                    </p:column>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

```
 public void selectedLocaleValue(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("selectedLocale inside action method "+event.getNewValue());
 ....}
```

Comment: When we copy'n'paste'n'run this snippet and stub all the missing parts with straightforward/documented code/defaults, then it works just fine for us. Please carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and post a real MCVE. So far, my educated guess says that your converter is broken. This is then the Q&A you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4734580

Comment: Yes. Thank you. The converter was the problem.