# JSF or PrimeFaces component for Boolean / how to use Boolean with p:triStateCheckbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` and `p:selectBooleanButton` can be linked to a primitive data type `boolean` variable in a controller.

I want to have a controller which can be linked to a reference data type `Boolean`. It must be able to show the `null`, `true` and `false` values.

The `p:triStateCheckbox` can be linked to a `String` variable, but not a `Boolean` value.

Is there any JSF / PrimeFaces UI component which can represent reference data type `Boolean` in a Java Controller?

Comment: You could write a converter for string to boolean and use the tri state component

Comment: 'Should' or even 'must' ... and @jasperdevries, it's `Boolean` not `boolean` ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje I was on my phone.. of course it should be `Boolean` ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should write a converter for `String` to `Boolean` if you want to use the `TriStateCheckbox` as explained in the [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/tristatecheckbox?id=getting-started-with-tristatecheckbox):

> TriStateCheckbox passes values “0”, “1”, “2” by default for each state and this can be customized using a converter.

So, use something like:

```
public class TriStateBooleanConverter implements Converter {

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    switch (value) {
      case "0": return null;
      case "1": return Boolean.TRUE;
      case "2": return Boolean.FALSE;
      default: throw new ConverterException();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    Boolean bool = (Boolean) value;
    if (bool == null) {
      return "0";
    }
    return bool ? "1" : "2";
  }

}
```

See also:

- [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter' - Why do I need a Converter in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-for-null-converter-why-do-i-need-a-converter)

Comment: Was this on your phone too? ;-)