# PrimeFaces p:autoComplete over List of Objects, failed Conversion

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having some trouble using `p:autoComplete` properly, I am trying to let a user search based on a text field of an object. Currently I have the following:

```
<p:autoComplete forceSelection="true" value="#{answer.destinationQuestion}"
                completeMethod="#{editorView.completeText}"
                var="destinationQuestion" itemLabel="#{destinationQuestion.questionText}"
                itemValue="#{destinationQuestion}"/>
```

```
public List<Question> completeText(String query) {
        List<Question> ret = new ArrayList<Question>();
        
        for(Section section : this.survey.getSections()) {
            for(Question question : section.getQuestion()) {
                if(question.getQuestionText() != null && question.getQuestionText().contains(query)) {
                    ret.add(question);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return ret;
    }
```

My expectation with this code is that the autoComplete would let a user select a single `Question` instance, but once a value is selected from the autoComplete and an update event is triggered, I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert Question@228bb9f7 of type class java.lang.String to class Question
```

It has been suggested that I use a converter, but I am confused why the value selected is being treated as a String rather than my Question object, since itemValue is defined to be a Question object.

Edit: This is on PrimeFaces 6.2

Comment: You are adding a `String question`  to the `List<Question> ret`

Comment: @Gumpf Please add the `Question` Code here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter' - Why do I need a Converter in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-for-null-converter-why-do-i-need-a-converter)

Comment: Yes, many thanks, I had not considered objects return by EL's to be treated as strings, but I suppose it makes sense. The omnifaces.ListConverter also seems to work for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, what I can tell you is, you are missing a custom converter class.
You should use it like `converter="#{questionConverter}"`.

For further reference you can see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_customconvertor_tag.htm)