# Invoking get method in EL expression causes conversion error

Tags: jsf, el, myfaces

I have a JSF hidden input on my app view that holds some object's attribute:

```
<h:inputHidden id="hidMyData" value="#{bean.myList.get(bean.listIndex).someAttr}" immediate="true"/>
```

Index that determines the right object, is also saved in session bean and is an integer:

```
public void setListIndex(int listIndex) {
    this.listIndex = listIndex;
}

public int getListIndex() {
    return listIndex;
}
```

If I run my app on Websphere Application Server 8.5.5, I'm getting a conversion error:

```
PrimeExceptio E   /pages/MyView.xhtml at line 566 and column 50 value="#{bean.myList.get(bean.listIndex).someAttr}": Cannot convert get of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer
```

At the same time if I run it as a portlet on IBM Portal 7, there's no error. In both cases I use MyFaces implementation version 2.0.17 and Primefaces 6.2.27.

What could cause this error?

EDIT1: Just realized that using square brackets instead of `get` method works fine:

```
<h:inputHidden id="hidMyData" value="#{bean.myList[bean.listIndex].someAttr}" immediate="true"/>
```

Anyway if someone has an explanation why this method works and the first one doesn't, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: What is the value of `#{bean.myList.get(bean.listIndex).someAttr}`?

Comment: @JasperdeVries It's a string, value depends on `listIndex`.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a string, but what is the value of the item that is failing?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I've tried with 0, an int, not a String. I don't understand why the conversion is even made. Bean attribute is an integer, not a String. What am I missing?

Comment: Basically all bound values are transferred as string (that's just how HTTP works). JSF will convert the string to the correct type. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/conversion-error-setting-value-for-null-converter-why-do-i-need-a-converter

Comment: @JasperdeVries that makes sense, I agree. But I still don't understand why does it work on IBM Portal 7, but not on IBM WAS 8.5.5. Same code, different result. The only thing I see is that I use resolvers `<el-resolver>com.ibm.faces20.portlet.PortletELResolver</el-resolver><el-resolver>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver</el-resolver>` on Portal, should I also include some in web application? I've never done that so far and I've never had any similar problems.