# Why does UISelectMany not convert selectItems to a list of objects?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Just found the following in the [Java EE Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html) for `javax.faces.component.UISelectMany`:

> *Obtain the Converter using the following algorithm: If the component
>   has an attached Converter, use it. If
>   not, look for a ValueExpression for
>   value (if any). The ValueExpression
>   must point to something that is:*
>
> - An array of primitives (such as       int[]). Look up the registered
>     by-class Converter for this primitive 
>     type.
> - An array of objects (such as    Integer[] or String[]). Look up the
>     registered by-class Converter for the 
>     underlying element type.
> - A java.util.Collection. Do not convert the values.

For a better understanding, I would like to know why the values won't be converted if the ValueExpression is a Collection.

If I want to attach a converter to UISelectMany, do I need to write a converter for the Collection or for the underlying element type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because EL don't/can't know about the generic list type, because it got lost during runtime. All it knows is that it's a collection of *something*. The items will be treated as `String` by default. You need to write a converter for the generic list type, not for the collection. See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/jsf-2-0-use-enum-in-selectmany-menu/3823776#3823776).

To learn more about the *type erasure* of Java generics, check the [generics tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf).

Comment: Hi BalusC. Thanks for the quick answer. The related answer from the given link makes it clear and I will try it this way. The link to the generics tutorial seems wrong (it redirects to the related answer)?

Comment: You're welcome. As to the wrong link, sorry, my Ctrl+C didn't do its job. I fixed it.

Comment: Yes it works! Great job, BalusC! But I had to override `getAsObject` and `getAsString` methods. Otherwise there were conversion errors like:  Error Rendering View[/benutzer/Create.xhtml]
java.lang.ClassCastException: jpa.entities.Benutzergruppe cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum at javax.faces.convert.EnumConverter.getAsString

Comment: The linked related answer concerns when using **enums** as list items. If you aren't using enums as list items, but just normal **classes**, you have to create a "normal" converter with `getAsObject()` and `getAsString()`, indeed. You don't need to extend `EnumConverter`. See also [this another related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/jsf-2-selection-combo-box-with-without-conversion-strategy/4735322#4735322).

Comment: Aha, I can see clearly now, the rain has gone: I had a Netbean's generated converter in my bean with the annotation `@FacesConverter(forClass = Benutzergruppe.class)`. This worked for UISelectOne but not for UISelectMany. The simple fix was to remove the `forClass` attribute to get it working with lists as well.