# How do I get selectManyCheckBox to return something other than List<String>?

Tags: jsf-2

This is a pattern that I would use over and over again if I get it to work.  I have an enum name Log.LogKey that I want to user to pick out instances of.  So the facelet has this:

```
             <h:form id="testForm" >

                <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.selectedKeys}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{test.allKeys}"
                                   var="lk"
                                   itemLabel="#{lk.display}"
                                   itemValue="#{lk}" />
                </h:selectManyCheckbox>

                <h:commandButton value="Do It" action="#{test.doNothng}" />

            </h:form>
```

The enum has a getter called **getDisplay()**.  The **selectItems** attribute calls that correctly because that's the string that gets rendered to the user. And the backing bean has this:

```
public class Test implements Serializable {

private List<Log.LogKey> selectedKeys = null;

public List<Log.LogKey> getAllKeys() {
    return Arrays.asList(Log.LogKey.values());
}

public List<Log.LogKey> getSelectedKeys() { return selectedKeys; }

public void setSelectedKeys(List selected) {
    System.out.println("getSelecgedKeus() got " + selected.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (Object obj : selected) {
        System.out.println(i++ + " is " + obj.getClass() + ":" + obj);
    }
}

public String doNothng() { return null; }
```

}

So on the form submit, the array **setSelectedKeys(selected)** gets called with a List of Strings, not a List of Log.LogKey.  The reference to **#{lk}** in the **selectItems** tag is converting the object to a string.  What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a converter. JSF EL is not aware about the generic `List` type because that's lost during runtime. When you do not explicitly specify a converter, JSF will not convert the submitted `String` values and plain fill the list with them.

In your particular case, you can make use of the JSF builtin [`EnumConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/EnumConverter.html), you just have to `super()` the enum type in the constructor:

```
package com.example;

import javax.faces.convert.EnumConverter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(value="logKeyConverter")
public class LogKeyConverter extends EnumConverter {

    public LogKeyConverter() {
        super(Log.LogKey.class);
    }

}
```

To use it, just declare it as follows:

```html
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{test.selectedKeys}" converter="logKeyConverter">
    ...
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

#### See also:

- [Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/jsf-2-0-use-enum-in-selectmany-menu/3823776#3823776)

Comment: I don't know how I missed that other posting.   Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you omitted "enum" as search keyword ;)