# f:selectItems and POJOs - once more

Tags: jsf

All the questions asking: how can I bind POJOs to h:selectXX with f:selectItems end up with answer "use a converter". However, it seems it is possible to go without the converter - see:

Facelet:

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{pojoBean.selected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{pojoBean.allItems}" var="i" itemValue="#{i}" itemLabel="#{i.txt}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Bean:

```
public class PojoBean {
    List<MyItem> selected;
    List<MyItem> allItems;
```

POJO:

```
public class MyItem {
    private String txt;
...}
```

Note that this seems to work only with h:selectManyListbox, when the value/s being selected end up in a list, not in a single property.

Question - why doesn't it work with h:selectOneMenu and etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely your `MyItem` class has already the `toString()` overridden which returns the `txt` and you were plain printing `selected` as follows to determine the selected values:

```
System.out.println(selected);
```

Try to cast each item of `selected` back to `MyItem`:

```
for (MyItem myItem : selected) {
    System.out.println(myItem);
}
```

You'll see that it fails with `ClassCastException`, because it's *actually* a `String`. So yes, you still need a converter here.

#### See also:

- [How do I get selectManyCheckBox to return something other than List<String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294284/how-do-i-get-selectmanycheckbox-to-return-something-other-than-liststring)

Comment: Damn, you're right :) I was actually printing with an EL in the view (refreshed with an f:ajax), the MyItem has toString overriden by standard Eclipse toString-generation. When I tried the foreach you mentioned it is really throwing ClassCastExceptions! Question comes how could a List<String> be passed to a List<MyItem> parameter, but as I understand it's about generics here - the MyItem type parameter gets lost and that's why JSF is able to pass there anything (i.e. String). THANKS!

Comment: That's answered in the "see also" link. JSF/EL isn't at all aware about the generic type of the `List` because that's by design completely lost during runtime. All JSF/EL knows is that it's a `List` and since there's no converter, it just adds unmodified/unconverted `String` submitted values to the `List`.