# Unexpected behaviour of diamond interface in JDK7

Tags: java, jsf

I have a property in my JSF managed bean:

```
private List<Long> selectedDataSets;
```

I initialize the list like this within an other method:

```
ArrayList<Long> longList = new ArrayList<>();
```

What happens is I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long` right when it jumps on this foreach:

```
for (Long CRC : selectedDataSets) { ... }
```

Which is very odd. Debug shows that `selectedDataSets` are full of `String` values, but I thought that's not even possible. Please describe me what exactly happened here.

Comment: That would depend totally on how and where you filled `longList`... could you have subverted the type checking in a method somewhere?  You've omitted the most important code from your sample.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you bound the property to an [`UISelectMany`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html) component like [`<h:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyCheckbox.html) or [`<selectManyListbox>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyListbox.html) without explicitly specifying a [`Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html). In Java, the [generic type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) is [erased](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101) during runtime and JSF (more specifically, EL) does not know anything about the generic list type at all and defaults to [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) unless told otherwise by a [`Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html). It's [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) because that's just the default value type of [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29). EL fills the list with submitted values by [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) and does not take any generic types into account.

So, for example this should do it for you, with help of the builtin [`LongConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/LongConverter.html):

```html
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedDataSets}" converter="javax.faces.Long">
```

#### See also:

- [Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/jsf-2-0-use-enum-in-selectmany-menu/3823776#3823776)

---

Note that this has nothing to do with Java 7's diamond operator. You would have exactly the same problem when you have experimented with `new ArrayList<Long>()`.

Comment: *embarrassed*. I think I never used any type other than `String`, so it would have been natural for me if it would have worked automatically with generics.

Comment: Please note that JSF/EL has also builtin coercions for standard Java types like `int`, `Integer`, `long`, `Long`, `boolean`, `Boolean`, `enum`, `Enum`, etc. This way you'd never need to explicitly specify a `Converter` for them. But for a `List` of them it's indeed a different story.