# JSF 2 selectOneMenu using label as value after form posts

Tags: jsf-2, dictionary, primefaces, el, selectonemenu

Here is my JSF's tag:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="myLocales" value="#{propertyBean.localeId}" editable="true" >  
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Locale" itemValue="" />  
     <f:selectItems  value="#{propertyBean.locales.entrySet()}" var ="map" itemValue="#{map.key}" itemLabel="#{map.value}" />  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Here is my propertyBean's getLocales() method :

```
public Map<Integer,String> getLocales() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Locale> locales = session.createCriteria(Locale.class)
                                    .list();
    Map<Integer,String> localeMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    for (Locale locale : locales) {
        localeMap.put(locale.getLocaleId(), locale.getLocaleName());
    }
    return localeMap;
}
```

After form posts, I am expecting the integer which I am setting as key in the Map as LocaleId on the server side, but unfortunately I am getting the String Label as LocaleId on the server side. Can you tell me why this inversion is happening and how I can correct it.

Comment: Can you verify that you're running EL2.2?

Comment: yes I am running EL2.2

Comment: Have you tried the [default way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10656919/1199132) of using a map? Also check what's rendering in your client side using firebug.