# Property 'value' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss5.x

I'm working with MVC project with primeface and jboss 5.1 . I had to migrate project to primeface latest version from primeface 3.4. I migrated that to 3.5 and then 4.0 . Now I'm trying to migrate that to primeface 5.0 . Then It gives this error message.

**description**
 The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /main.xhtml @103,58 itemLabel="#{item.value}": Property 'value' not found on type java.lang.String
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:422)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:696)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:57)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

and part of my main.xhtml is bellow

```
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="compType" value="#{authenticateController.userSession.mwtUmUser.companyType}" effect="fold" editable="false" style="width: 180px;">                           
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{authenticateController.companyTypeMap}"
                            var="item"
                            itemLabel="#{item.value}"
                            itemValue="#{item.key}"/>
                        <p:ajax listener="#{authenticateController.setUserCompanyType}" update=":loginFrm:loginGrd"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**`authenticateController`**

```
    public Map<String, String> getCompanyTypeMap() {

            try {
                if (null == commonManager) {
                    commonManager = (CommonManager) SpringUtil.getApplicationContext().getBean("commonManager");
                }
                companyTypeMap = commonManager.getCompanyTypeMap(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e, e);
            }
            return companyTypeMap;
        }


 public String getCompanyType() {
        return companyType;}
```

I already tried some similar  problems in stack-overflow but still not good result. plz help me out..

Comment: What type does authenticateController.getCompanyTypeMap() return ?

Comment: Please post your controller code

Comment: for test I just removed                                                                                                  'itemLabel="#{item.value}"
itemValue="#{item.key}"  '                                                                               Then project run with out errors. but I could not click on some sub menu. They did not worked.

Comment: an [mcve] instead of these huge amounts of code will increase your chance of getting help

Comment: Map<String, String> getCompanyTypeMap()

Answer (score 1):

Without a code of your `authenticateController` I could only suppose, that you are trying to use the `java.util.Map` interface behind the `#{authenticateController.companyTypeMap}` call. Please read the [BalusC answer on how to use maps with selectItems tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10656919/1324287).