# Hasmap is not being displayed on selectOneMenu

Tags: java, hashmap, selectonemenu

I've been strugling with selectOneMenu dinamically populated by a HashMap without success for a day now, and can´t find what´s going on. 
Followed the steps on

[How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database)

but still no luck

Here´s my bean:

```
private Paciente selectedPaciente;
private Map<String, String> itensPacientes; 


@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        itensPacientes = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        itensPacientes.put("1","teste1");
        itensPacientes.put("2","teste1");
        itensPacientes.put("3","teste1");     
}


public Map<String, String> getItensPacientes() {
        return itensPacientes;
}

public Paciente getSelectedPaciente(){
        return selectedPaciente;
}

public void setSelectedPaciente(Paciente selectedPaciente){
        this.selectedPaciente = selectedPaciente;
}
```

and here's the jsf portion

```
    <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{beanAgenda.selectedPaciente}" required="true">   
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--select--" />       
        <f:selectItems value="#{beanAgenda.itensPacientes}" 
           itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

But when I run the code, I can only see the "--select--" option on the combobx.
Is there something I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{beanAgenda.itensPacientes.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
       itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>
```

Answer and explanation from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655349/jsf-2-fselectitems-with-map-does-not-display-itemlabel)

Comment: Yeah I tried that but still not working  
<f:selectItems value="#{beanAgenda.itensPacientes.entrySet()}" var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/>

Comment: Found the problem. It was the beanName. I was using beanAgenda instead of agendaBean,