# EnumConverter in primefaces editable datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, converters

I wrote an EnumConverter that is described in [Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/jsf-2-0-use-enum-in-selectmany-menu#answer-3823776)? Everything was fine until we recognize that this converter does not work properly in primefaces editable datatable. The problem is that although I added an attribute inside getAsString and getAsObject methods as following:

```
@Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Enum) {
            component.getAttributes().put(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE, value.getClass());
            return ((Enum<?>) value).name();
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Value is not an enum: " + value.getClass()));
        }
    }
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Class<Enum> enumType = (Class<Enum>) component.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE);
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(enumType, value);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Value is not an enum of type: " + enumType));
        }
    }
```

In the latter method(`getAsObject`) could not find the attribute that I gave to the components attribute map. But out of the pprimefaces editable datatable everything is fine. Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused because the custom component attribute was not saved in the row state of the PrimeFaces datatable (it works fine in standard `h:dataTable`).

We're going to need to store this information elsewhere. In the view scope along with the component ID would be one way.

In the `getAsString()`:

```
context.getViewRoot().getViewMap().put(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE + component.getId(), value.getClass());
```

And in the `getAsObject()`:

```
Class<Enum> enumType = (Class<Enum>) context.getViewRoot().getViewMap().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE + component.getId());
```