# SelectManyBox - Enum Not saving

Tags: jsf, enums, selectmanycheckbox

I still have problem with selectManyCheckBox..

selectManyCheckBox:

```
 <p:selectManyCheckbox converter="genericEnumConverter" value="#{aView.newObject.aValue}">                                           
        <f:selectItems value="#{enumBean.aValueValues}" var="s" itemValue="#{s}" itemLabel = "#{s.name}"/>
 </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Converter for this selectManyCheckBox is the same as described here:
[Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/jsf-2-0-use-enum-in-selectmany-menu/3823776#3823776)

```
@FacesConverter("genericEnumConverter")
public class GenericEnumConverter implements Converter {

    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE = "GenericEnumConverter.enumType";

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        System.out.println("getAsString 1: ");
        if (value instanceof Enum) {
            System.out.println("getAsString 2: ");
            component.getAttributes().put(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE, value.getClass());
            System.out.println("getAsString 3: ");
            return ((Enum<?>) value).name();
        } else {
            System.out.println("getAsString 4: ");
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Value is not an enum: " + value.getClass()));
        }        
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("getAsObject 1: ");
        Class<Enum> enumType = (Class<Enum>) component.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENUM_TYPE);
        System.out.println("getAsObject 2: ");
        try {
            System.out.println("getAsObject 3: ");
            return Enum.valueOf(enumType, value);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("getAsObject 4: ");
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Value is not an enum of type: " + enumType));
        }
    }
```

The enum is:

```
public enum aValue {

        1Value,
        2Value,
        3Value,
        4Value;
        private final String name;

        private aValue() {
            System.out.println("aValue 1");
            this.name = null;
            System.out.println("aValue 2");
        }

        public String getName() {
            System.out.println("getName 1 " + name());
            return ResourceBundleUtil.getLabelFromRb("aValue." + name());
        }
    }

    public aValue[] getAValueValues() {
        return AValue.values();
    }
```

Tomcat Logs are:

```
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
aValue 1
aValue 2
getName 1Value
getName 2Value
getName 3Value
getName 4Value
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getName 1Value
getName 2Value
getName 3Value
getName 4Value
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3: 
getAsString 1: 
getAsString 2: 
getAsString 3:
```

When I press save button, nothing happens and nothing is saved into database. It looks like it is not going into getAsObject method. I don't know why. When I change the component into a SelectOneMenu there is no problem. But this selectManyCheckBox thing is not working. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: If you are using `p:commandButton` add attribute `ajax="false"` and check event is firing or not.

Comment: My approch for thoses situations is to put a breakpoint on  processDecodes(FacesContext context) and getConvertedValue(context, submittedValue) of javax.faces.component.UIinput and to look for the request parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox ... value="#{aView.newObject.aValue}">
```

You're binding the `value` attribute of an input component which can get/set **multiple** values to a property which represents a **single** value. This isn't going to work. You need to bind the `value` attribute to a collection (e.g. `List<aValue>`) or array (e.g. `aValue[]`) property instead of a single property `aValue`.

For example:

```
public class NewObject {

    private List<aValue> aValues;

    // ...
}
```

with

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox ... value="#{aView.newObject.aValues}">
```

Or, alternatively:

```
public class NewObject {

    private aValue[] aValues;

    // ...
}
```

with

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{aView.newObject.aValues}">
```

Note that when you use arrays, the whole converter is **not** needed. See also [`omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter` showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter;jsessionid=Ubynyj30h9X8mn+zdIzaR3VO).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, according to Java Naming Conventions, enum class names should start with uppercase, like as with regular classes and interfaces, so `aValue` as enum class name is really a bad choice. Hungarian notations are also discouraged in Java, by the way.

---

**Update**: to prove its working, here's an SSCCE.

The enum:

```
public enum Value {

    ONE, TWO, THREE;

    public String getName() {
        return name().toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

The entity:

```
public class Entity {

    private Value[] values;

    public Value[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(Value[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

The managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped // Note: @ViewScoped works as well on this SSCCE.
public class Bean {

    private Entity entity;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        entity = new Entity();
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(entity.getValues()));
    }

    public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public Value[] getAvailableValues() {
        return Value.values();
    }

}
```

The view (without any converter!):

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.entity.values}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableValues}" var="value"
            itemValue="#{value}" itemLabel="#{value.name}" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox> 
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" /> 
</h:form>
```

It works just fine for me (Mojarra 2.1.28 + PrimeFaces 4.0, but should work on all older versions as well as this construct isn't previously known to have any bugs).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I tried using arrays, but didn't work. The output is: http://codeshare.io/tTJDY I changed the code like this:
http://codeshare.io/O7eNb

Comment: Well, apparently `#{aView.newObject}` is `null`, or the input is simply not covered by ajax process. Hard to tell without seeing a true SSCCE.

Comment: Note: In the original code I obeyed the Java Naming Conventions. But when I transfer the code here, I made a mistake. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: I was not setting the value in the bean. When did it, it worked. Thanks!