# How to get a localized message from enum displayed

Tags: jsf-2, properties, localization, enums, el

i have for instance an

```
enum State { OK, WARN, ERROR }
```

and a `message.properties` with following keys:

```
my.state.OK=Ok
my.state.WARN=Warning
my.state.ERROR=Error
```

and given a bean with a property of type `State`, for instance, `bean.state`, i would like to display the text for the property's state.

something like:

```
#{text['my.state.' + bean.state]}
```

this does not seem to be possible just because the `+` operator does not work on strings.

any work around?

Comment: never mind, i got it: `<ui:param name="msgKey" value="my.state.#{bean.state}" />` and `#{text[msgKey]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra property to the enum representing the label key.

```
public enum State {

    OK, WARN, ERROR;

    private String labelKey;

    private State() {
        this.labelKey = "my.state." + name();
    }

    public String getLabelKey() {
        return labelKey;
    }

}
```

So that you can reference it as follows:

```
#{text[bean.state.labelKey]}
```

This way you don't need to repeat `<ui:param name="msgKey" value="my.state.#{bean.state}" />` over all place.

#### See also:

- [How to use enum values in f:selectItem(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-make-a-dropdown-menu-of-a-enum-in-jsf/8229982#8229982)