# Cannot convert J of type class java.lang.String to class xxx

Tags: java, type-conversion, el

I have a enum named PersonType :

```
public enum PersonType {

    AAA ("F"),
    BBB ("J");

    private final String id;

    private PersonType(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Person class :

```
public void setpersonType(PersonType tipoPessoa) {
    this.des_tipoPessoa = tipoPessoa;
}
```

In my bean I have in init :

class named Pessoa setting the pesonType

```
pessoa.setpersonType(PersonType.BBB);
```

in my xhtml I have  :

```
<div id="divPJ" style="display:#{pessoaMB.pessoa.des_tipoPessoa ne 'J' ? 'none' : 'block'}">
```

I got the such error :

javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot convert J of type class java.lang.String to class myproject PersonType

*what is the right way to compare `#{pessoaMB.pessoa.des_tipoPessoa ne 'J'`*

Primefaces radio :

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{pessoaMB.pessoa.des_tipoPessoa}" ...
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching a bit more this time, I found this BalusC answer and I can fixed my issue.

Thanks BalusC and Stack community.

[How to make a dropdown menu of a enum in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-make-a-dropdown-menu-of-a-enum-in-jsf)