# h:selectOneMenu with values from an enum becomes null after reload

Tags: jsf, enums

I followed the advice from [How to use enum values in f:selectItem(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-make-a-dropdown-menu-of-a-enum-in-jsf) to build a h:selectOneMenu that takes the values of an enum. This works fine until I reload the page.

If I reload the page (Strg+R) what a user could do, the #{bean.relationship} property becomes *null*. All other properties, such as strings, numbers, etc. remain as they were before (Bean is @ViewScoped and @ManagedBean).

Here is the code from the JSF:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.relationship}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.relationshipTypes}" 
        var="types" itemValue="#{types}" itemLabel="#{types}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText value="#{bean.name}" />
```

Here the code from the Enum:

```
public enum RelationshipType {
   Family,
   Friend    
}
```

Here the code from the Bean:

```
private RelationshipType relationship; // plus getter & setter
private RelationshipType[] relationshipTypes;
private String name; // plus getter & setter

public RelationshipType[] getRelationshipTypes() {
    return RelationshipType.values();
}
```

The enum is part of a larger entity. For ease of display a shortend version. Any idea?

@Geinmachi: Yet, other values stored in the bean are still there after the reload (e.g. name). So, why not for the property related to the enum?

Comment: After page refresh the state of `@ViewScoped` is not preserved.

Comment: And how is this 'enum' related? If it does  work for an arrayList of strings, please create a [mcve]

Comment: @Geinmachi: true, but that would be true for strings, numbers etc too. Unless the automagic string-enum conversion fails...

Answer (score -1):

I have used enums for data types

**Enum**

```
public enum Datatypes {
INT("Int"), FLOAT("Float"), DOUBLE("Double"), STRING("String"), DATE("Date"), DATETIME(
        "DateTime"), BLOB("Blob");

private final String dataType;

private Datatypes(String dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

public String getDataType() {
    return this.dataType;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return dataType;
}
```

}

**Bean**

```
private List<Datatypes> datatypes = Arrays.asList(Datatypes.values());

public List<Datatypes> getDatatypes() {
    return datatypes;
}

public void setDatatypes(List<Datatypes> datatypes) {
    this.datatypes = datatypes;
}
```

**xhtml**

```
 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.dataType}">
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Data type"/>
 <f:selectItems value="#{bean.dataTypes}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

it working for me.

Comment: You're not answering the question.