# How to store a char but show a String

Tags: jsf

It's sad that I have to ask for this, but how can I store a char in my Postgres DB, but show String for the selection of the value.
I'm creating a web application with JSF.

So my .xhtml:

```
<p:outputLabel for="gender" value="Geschlecht:" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="gender" value="#{telefonbuchController.telefonbuch.gender}" style="width:125px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Auswählen" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{telefonbuchController.genderList}" var="c" itemLabel="#{gender}" itemValue="#{gender}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Model:

```
@Column
private char gender;
```

In the controller for the form I create a list of Strings for male and female and init them with PostConstruct.

```
private List<String> geschaeftsstellen;
```

[image: This]

Here you see how it should look. I implemented it with a String, but I want to just store 'm' and 'f' in my database instead of the whole string.

Comment: It feels like you need an `enum` and not `char`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use enum values in f:selectItem(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-use-enum-values-in-fselectitems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement it like this:

```
public enum Gender {
MALE('m'),
FEMALE('f')
;

private char shortGender;

public Gender (char shortGender) {
    this.shortGender = shortGender;
}

public char getShortGender() {
    return shortGender;
}

}
```

And in your template use different values for `itemLabel` and `itemValue`, i.e.:

```
itemLabel="#{gender}" itemValue="#{gender.shortGender}"
```

Comment: Many of these basic jsf things have Q/A with many upvotes. Sorting on votes and reading the, and remember their existence/titles helps a lot. Saves you writing questions! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-use-enum-values-in-fselectitems Voting as duplicate instead of answering saves time too ;-) And the company is? (Just curious)

Comment: adesso @Kukeltje

Comment: @smsnheck +1 then

Comment: How do I store it in the database? I mean I get the error that it cannot convert the type String to class Gender...