# can't access to suffixs or enum's values in primefaces <p:selectOneMenu component.. any solution?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, joinfaces

Hi I am currently working on a java project (jsf) with primefaces and I am using enum, but I cannot access its values from the view with primefaces. I have temporarily solved the problem by creating a getter from the Bean and accessing the enum values, but it should work with allSuffix = "ALL_ENUM_VALUES" or ALL_VALUES by default, I don't know if it's a problem with primefaces, joinfaces or something I'm missing. I have looked into the official documentation and it should work... any solution?

my code is

````
<p:importEnum
        type="com.path.enumeration.AltoMedioBajo"
        var="AltoMedioBajo"
        allSuffix="ALL_ENUM_VALUES" />

                    <p:outputLabel
                        for="posibilidad"
                        value="#{informe_msg.posibilidad}" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu
                        id="posibilidad"
                        style="width: 150px"
                        value="#{informeSeguimientoDto.specification.posibilidad}">
                        <f:selectItem
                            itemLabel=""
                            itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{AltoMedioBajo.ALL_ENUM_VALUES}"
                            var="posibilidad"
                            itemValue="#{posibilidad}"
                            itemLabel="#{peticion_msg[posibilidad.femKey]}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Hi this question was answered here: [How to use enum values in f:selectItem(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-use-enum-values-in-fselectitems)

With joinfaces I tested this example:

**User Bean**

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserBean {

    public Role[] getRoles() {
        return Role.values();
    }
}
```

**add_user.xhtml**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="roleId" value="#{userBean.newUser.roleId}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.roles}" var="role" itemValue="#{role.getId()}" itemLabel="#{messages['role_' += role]}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Role Enum** with custom order, it's not mandatory you can use default .ordinal() value

```
public enum Role {
ASSISTANT(1),
ACCOUNTANT(4),
CASHIER(5),
ADMIN(10);

private final int id;

Role(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
// method to get the Role using Id from the database
public static Role valueOf(int id) {
    return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(role -> role.id == id)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}}
```

**messages_es.properties** as Resource Bundle

```
role_ASSISTANT=Asistente
role_ACCOUNTANT=Contador
role_CASHIER=Cajero
role_ADMIN=Administrador
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation/demo](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/importEnum.xhtml), you should use a `repeat` tag.

**Edited**: Try this version:

```
<p:importEnum type="com.path.enumeration.AltoMedioBajo" var="AltoMedioBajo"
              allSuffix="ALL_ENUM_VALUES" />

<p:outputLabel for="posibilidad" value="#{informe_msg.posibilidad}" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="posibilidad" style="width: 150px"
                 value="#{informeSeguimientoDto.specification.posibilidad}">
    <f:selectItem />
    <ui:repeat var="posibilidad" value="#{AltoMedioBajo.ALL_ENUM_VALUES}">  
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{posibilidad}"
                      itemLabel="#{peticion_msg[posibilidad.femKey]}"
    </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: it does not work for me. there is another possibility to use a ui: repeat to simulate a selectOneMenu ?

Comment: I need to use selectonemenu component with an enum but it doesn't work