# How to display all enum values as <f:selectItems> with enum property as label

Tags: jsf, datatable, enums, selectonemenu, omnifaces

I have a `RoleStatus` enum which is as being a property of `Role` entity mapped to an integer in the DB (but that part is irrelevant). I'd like to present a `List<Role>` in a `<p:dataTable>` in which one column should have a `<h:selectOneMenu>` for the `RoleStatus` property of the `Role` entity. How can I implement this with or without [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org)?

Here's the enum:

```
public enum RoleStatus {

    ACTIVE(1, "Active"),
    DISABLE(2, "Disable");

    private final int intStatus;
    private final String status;

    private RoleStatus(int intStatus, String status) {
        this.intStatus = intStatus;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getIntStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

}
```

Here's the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RoleController {

    private List<Role> roles;

    @ManagedProperty("#{roleService}")
    private IRoleService roleService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        roles = roleService.getRoles();
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

}
```

Finally, the data table where I'd like to have a `<h:selectOneMenu>` for the `RoleStatus` property of `Role` entity, showing all available enum values as select item options.

```
<h:form id="roleForm">
    <p:dataTable value="#{roleController.roles}" var="role">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{role.roleid}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{role.role}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{role.description}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{role.roleStatus}">
                <!-- How??? -->
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

How can I achieve this? Do I need the [OmniFaces `SelectItemsConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF 2.0: use Enum values for selectOneMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868778/jsf-2-0-use-enum-values-for-selectonemenu)

Comment: Not quite! i have the the data showing as Integer in database and datatable. i need to display it correctly in the datatable as say "Active" or "disabled" dpending on the integer value.

Comment: using omnifaces Converter, i was able to get the status column to display but as arrays  of "[Active, Disabled]". some of the values need to be "Active" and Some "Disabled"

Comment: Like one of the answers in the post I linked , you just need to implement a converter

Comment: Am sorry but i don't have issues with drop-downs. i have issues with the datatable.

Comment: You're missing the point by miles: the same principle that applies to all jsf controls. Please [**read the JSF wiki**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) to learn more about JSF and converters

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a converter. JSF has already a builtin enum converter.

Without OmniFaces, here's how you could provide the enum values as available items of `<h:selectOneMenu>`:

1. Add this method to `RoleController`:

   ```
   public RoleStatus[] getRoleStatuses() {
       return RoleStatus.values();
   }
   ```

   This way, all enum values are available by `#{roleController.roleStatuses}`.
2. Then use this dropdown:

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{role.roleStatus}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{roleController.roleStatuses}" var="roleStatus"
           itemValue="#{roleStatus}" itemLabel="#{roleStatus.status}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   ```

   Note: as those values are static/applicationwide, it doesn't hurt to move the method to a separate `@ApplicationScoped` bean.

   ---

With OmniFaces, you could remove the additional getter and just import the enum directly via [`<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants):

1. Add this somewhere in top of your template (assuming that it's in `com.example` package):

   ```
   <o:importConstants type="com.example.RoleStatus" />
   ```

   This way, the enum class itself is available by `#{RoleStatus}` (note the capitalization!).
2. Then use this dropdown:

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{role.roleStatus}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{RoleStatus.values()}" var="roleStatus"
           itemValue="#{roleStatus}" itemLabel="#{roleStatus.status}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   ```

Comment: I believe the Ominfaces library has been updated in the mean time so that `<f:selectItems value="#{RoleStatus}" ...` also works, without needing the `.values()` method call. **Note capitalization though.**

Comment: @fr13d: nothing changed there. I was just using `values()` because item label needed `#{roleStatus.status}` and this was just easier.